# libGLESv2_adreno.so game crash in Galaxy Note 4 and Lollipop 5.0

Tags: android, opengl-es, libgdx, android-5.0-lollipop, galaxy

Some users of my game that are trying to play it in a Samsung Galaxy Note 4 updated to Android Lollipop 5.0 are experiencing a game crash at startup:

```
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/trlteuc/trlteatt:5.0.1/LRX22C/N910AUCU1COC2:user/release-keys'
Revision: '12'
ABI: 'arm'
pid: 20911, tid: 20927, name: GLThread 270611 >>> com.mangoprotocol.psychotic.mechanika <<<
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
r0 00000000 r1 000051bf r2 00000006 r3 00000000
r4 b39ffdb8 r5 00000006 r6 00000002 r7 0000010c
r8 a0e1a140 r9 00000000 sl 00000001 fp aa934c40
ip 000051bf sp b39ff830 lr b6e8cff5 pc b6eb0998 cpsr 600b0010

backtrace:
#00 pc 00037998 /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
#01 pc 00013ff1 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+52)
#02 pc 00014c0f /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
#03 pc 00011531 /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+36)
#04 pc 0000fcbc /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
#05 pc 00001259 /system/lib/libstdc++.so
#06 pc 00000afb /system/lib/libstdc++.so (__cxa_pure_virtual+6)
#07 pc 000e4595 /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (EsxGlObject::DecRefCount(EsxContext*)+28)
#08 pc 000b4b67 /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (EsxContext::GlUseProgram(unsigned int)+150)
#09 pc 000e02d3 /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (EsxGlApiParamValidate::GlUseProgram(EsxDispatch*, unsigned int)+34)
#10 pc 000abd75 /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (glUseProgram+44)
#11 pc 002e9887 /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.mangoprotocol.psychotic.mechanika-1@base.apk@classes.dex
```

I don't know if this is related to the OpenGL ES driver for the GPU (Adreno 420) if it is a more general issue with the OS (Android Lollipop 5.0), or if it has something to do with libGDX (the game framework I'm using). What I know is that the games works like a charm in a Nexus 6 (also with Adreno 420) updated to Lollipop 5.1.

Do you have any idea about how to solve this issue or how to work around it?

Comment: The C libraries will sometimes abort() if they fail required memory allocations.  You could be running low on memory on this device/configuration?  (Its definitely a bug that an app could trigger this failure).  Also it looks like the failure happens during shader setup.  Do you have fun/interesting shaders?

Comment: I have a blur shader coded but it is disabled, so it is not being compiled at runtime. How could this be an issue?

Comment: Hi @jgg, did you happen to fix this issue? I think we are seeing the same case with our app...

Comment: No clue about this issue @Sean. And I've received the same report from a Samsung Galaxy Note Edge user with Android 5.0 as well.

Comment: @jgg yes, we actually had a report about note edge as well. I suggest you post a question in Qualcomm developers blog.